# ResolveUrl in Static WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, resolveurl

How do you resolve a url like "../../images/test.png" to "http://yoursite.com/images/test.png" in a static asp.net web method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a blog entry from Rick Strahl that might help: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/154812.aspx

Comment: jip, that is a really good article, but if I understand the code correctly it would not work for situations where your have ../../../ etc in the url. but I could be wrong

Comment: Is the images folder in the root directory? If so, replace ../../ with ~/   That is what the resolver is supposed to do, change ~/ to the appropriate path, depending on the nesting level of the page.

Comment: i cannot replace ../../ with ~/ as any number of ../ relative paths to various pages and files can be passed to my static webmethod. i therefore need a way to convert a relative path such as ../1/2/3/4/page.aspx to http ://abc.com/a/b/s/1/2/3/4/page.aspx

Comment: Ok, I think you need to provide more examples of what you need to do in your question

Answer (score 1):

look in `HttpContext.Current.Request`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the current Context and application paths together:

```
    Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url,
                System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath,
                "Reports/CareerDev.aspx"));
    return uri.AbsoluteUri;
```